# rdkafka 0.8.1 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm runnning `bundle install` Then I get this error:

```
Fetching rdkafka 0.8.1
Installing rdkafka 0.8.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Extracting v1.4.0 into tmp//ports/librdkafka/1.4.0... OK
Running 'configure' for librdkafka 1.4.0... ERROR, review '/Users/codegeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@ls-member/gems/rdkafka-0.8.1/ext/tmp/ports/librdkafka/1.4.0/configure.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
source: 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void foo (void) {
   int s = socket(0, 0, 0);
   close(s);
}

 libpthread () 
    module: self
    action: fail
    reason:
compile check failed:
CC: CC
flags: -lpthread
  -g -O2 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wall -Werror _mkltmpVFiBMn.c -o _mkltmpVFiBMn.c.o   -lpthread:
mklove/modules/configure.base: line 1349: -g: command not found
source: #include <pthread.h>
```

But then it will suggest to do:

```
Make sure that `gem install rdkafka -v '0.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I'll run `gem install rdkafka -v '0.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` but then
it will produce an error too

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdkafka:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by providing the following compilation flags

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib gem install rdkafka -v '0.8.1'
```

I was able to find the answer [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/373#issuecomment-372425468)

Hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

just run the following on your terminal:

`xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Luan answer I could fix my error. I have 2 homebrews installed which creates a mess in some occasions.
If you are in an arm silicon macos try

```sh
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include/ LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib gem install rdkafka -v '0.10.0'
```